# Can't build Apk with Firebase Analytic 4.1.0 & Admob 3.7.0

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, admob, firebase-analytics

I got the error when trying to build apk from a simple Unity3D project. Do there step to reproduce issue (I use Unity 3D 5.6.1p4)
1. Download and imported Firebase Analytics 4.1.0. Do something to setup, such as adding json.... You will can not run "resolve jars" because android resolver has an issue. [Gradle failed to fetch dependencies](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/63). Need to be updated.
2. Replace android resolver by lastest version - [Android Resolver 1.2.50](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/play-services-resolver-1.2.50.0.unitypackage).
 Now you can build apk and Analytic works
3. Download and imported [Admob Plugin 3.7.0](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/3.7.0). Now you can't build because of an error. "resolve" and "force resolve" can't help.
There are log for error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Leo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzehl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzehm;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzehk;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbbw;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbbx;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbby;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbbz;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbca;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:313)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:291)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive C:\Sources\Unity5\Kong Run 2D\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
processing com/google/unity/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/AdNetworkExtras.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$6.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$7.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$6.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$7.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$8.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/PluginUtils.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityAdLoaderListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityRewardBasedVideoAdListener.class...
processing archive C:\Sources\Unity5\Kong Run 2D\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-11.2.0\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/measurement/
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementContentProvider.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementJobService.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementReceiver.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementService.class...
processing archive C:\Sources\Unity5\Kong Run 2D\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-impl-11.2.0\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/internal/
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcag.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcah.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcai.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcal.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcam.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcan.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcao.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcap.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcar.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcas.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcat.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcau.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcav.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcax.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcay.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcba.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbe.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcby.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcbz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcca.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcce.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcch.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcci.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcck.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcco.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcco$zza.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcct.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzccz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcda.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcde.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcds.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcea.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcec.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzced.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcee.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcef.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcei.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcej.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcek.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcel.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcem.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcen.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcep.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcer.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzces.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcet.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzceu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcev.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcew.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcex.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcey.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcez.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfe.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcff.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcft.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcfz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcga.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcgb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcgc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcgd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcge.class...
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/measurement/
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$Event.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$OnEventListener.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$Param.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$UserProperty.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$zza.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$zzb.class...
ignored resource com/google/firebase/
ignored resource com/google/firebase/analytics/
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.class...
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics$Event.class...
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics$Param.class...
processing com/google/firebase/<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by update dependencies file. Open GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml from path.

```
Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Editor\GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml
```

Change "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2" to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0". Run "Tools\Player Services Resovler\Android Resolver\Force Resolve". Build will work now.
if "11.2.0" doesn't work, try to change older version.

Comment: FYI: The 4.2.0 version of the Firebase SDK https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.2.0 includes the 1.2.53 version of the Play Services Resolver (https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) which automatically fixes conflicting Play Services versions for you.